# Hyper-V VM running Ubuntu Running into Black Screen Problem

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I'm using Hyper-V. I have downloaded Ubuntu MATE onto a VM and when I make the virtual machine connection I get the following message initially...
[image]

Then the Ubuntu Mate logo loading screen presents itself and all seems well. However... then this happens.
[image]

Darkness... nothing happens no matter how long I wait. Any ideas what is happening? I have restarted it a dozen times and out of those dozen times, there was *one* time when it said the following:

1. Failed to start detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes
2. Failed to start Light Display Manager.

But all the other times, it simply followed the sequence I have shown you. Initially the installation was going smoothly, this problem just occurred when I had to do the reboot to complete the installation... and I've been stuck here since.